# Sharing internet connection with tablet over a proxy-server

Tags: wireless, networking, server, proxy, tablet

I have a proxy-server at home and set up my ubuntu accordingly. All works fine. My setup is that you can only gain internet access over that proxy.

Now I have setup a raspberry pi with an edimax wireless adapter to act as an accesspoint with dns, dhcp and nat and all is runnning smooth.

I connected a tablet(Nexus7) to that new wireless network and all works fine.
My Internal tablet-ip is 192.168.10.100 and when i ping to my proxy-server the raspberry pi successfully replaces it with his own ip. (wireshark proven)

The problem now is that I cant gain internet access with my tablet. In wireshark my Tablet is not adressing the proxy but tries to directly access the ip from google for example.

These two pictures show a capture from the outgoing network card. The network card with internet access.

Wrong Requesst from tablet
[image: Wrong Request sent from tablet]

Right Request from raspberry pi (The ...5.179 is the proxy-server)
[image: Right Request sent from raspberry pi]

The Question is: How can I make the Tablet adress the right proxy without manually adding the proxy into its setup?

Is there a "real" internet connection sharing where the networkcard of my raspberry answers the requests? The current setup rather seems like forwarding to me.

My iptables look like that:

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination         

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination         
 ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
```

with commands entered:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```